# How to make std::get to be member method(s)?

Tags: c++, templates, tuples

`std::get` [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) gets elements of a tuple. The overloaded function has a number of versions. If I have a class derived from a tuple, and want to introduce a member method Get() to get tuple elements by using std::get. Do I need to write a member method for each version of std::get or I can only write one?

```
template<class... Args>
class Data
    : public std::tuple<Args...>
{
public:
    typedef std::tuple<Args...> TupleTy;

    // This is only one version.
    template<unsigned N>
    (typename std::tuple_element<N, TupleTy>::type)& Get()
    {
        return std::get<N>(*this);
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't think `std::tuple` was intended to be inherited from, at least not publicly.

Comment: I'm with chris; composition (rather than inheritance) is probably the way to go here.  However, the question of writing wrapper functions for the `std::get(std::tuple)` is a separate matter.  Even though there are 6 `std::get(std::tuple)` methods, you only really need two: `Get(index)` and `Get<class>()`.  They come in two flavors, returning copies or returning references.  Do you want your users to be able to alter the data or not?  Seeing as you have publicly inherited, I think you want it public.  You only need the functions that return `T&&` (compiler will cast to `const T&` when needed.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I use it in my internal classes, not for users.